# Book recommendations for functional analysis and analysis on manifolds to study optimization.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, optimization, book-recommendation

I'm about to start a PhD in an optimization lab, and I'd like to study some analysis beforehand.

So far, I've studied linear, non-linear, and integer optimization during my undergrad courses, and they were pretty theoretical. However, I've heard that functional analysis and analysis on manyfolds also hold many important results for optimization (mostly for non-linear), and I'd like to take a look before the PhD starts. For functional analysis, my uni uses the Kreyszig's book, and a random one for analysis on manyfolds.

However, I'm aware that only a few chapters in these books are directly relevant to optimization. For instance, in Kreyszig's book, I know that the sections on metric spaces and Banach's fixed point theorem are essential, but I'm uncertain about the rest.

In a nutshell: Could you guys recommend me some books and chapters in each book that will be most helpful for this purpose? :)

Comment: My two recommendations are: "Variational Analysis" R. Tyrrell Rockafellar and "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces" Heinz H. Bauschke , Patrick L. Combettes. I would start with the Variational Analysis book. The monotone operator book is a dry read, but it is dense with a lot of results.

Comment: A fairly readable book on functional analysis and its application to optimization is "Optimization by Vector Space Methods" by Luenberger.

Comment: I certainly join to the previous excellent recommendations.  Another enjoyable book chapter, which presents a condensed but excellent review of a somewhat more advanced theory (starts from topological vector spaces), is chapter 2 in "Perturbation Analysis of Optimization Problems", see https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1394-9